# How to make a fill-in-the-blank presentation

Tags: beamer, animate

I want to make a presentation with LaTeX. My problem is that I want to have on the current slide, at anytime I'd like to positionate (e.g. "The gras __ green"), some text only shown underlined without the text. Then I want to annotate at this underlinded line. After that I want on the next slide I want text and the underlining (e.g. "The gras __is green" with the "is" on the underlining). Is it possible to create a command that makes it automatically possible?

Thank you very much in advance for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure to understand. Do you want something like this?

[image]

I've created two new commands `\texthide` and `\textshow`

```
\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{#1}}
```

the first to be used when you want the text to be hidden and the latter when you what the text to be shown.

They have to be used as in the following example (which produces the above result)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
The gras \texthide{is} green
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
The gras \textshow{is} green
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

### EDIT

It doesn't change much if you want to use them in the same `frame` separated by a `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\texthide}[1]{\underline{\phantom{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\textshow}[1]{\underline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\only<1>{The gras \texthide{is} green}
\pause
\only<2>{The gras \textshow{is} green}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! But it isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The "fill-in-the-blank"-function should be on the same frame at the same position (e.g. separated by \pause), that the shown Pdf-pagenumber is the same, but latex produce two pages with the same pagenumber, but one with the only underlinded and the next with underlined and the text.

Comment: @RainerM. Is it OK now?

Comment: The output is exactly what i want, thank you! I hoped it is possible to automating the slidenumber to something like:
"\only<n>{The gras \texthide{is} green}
\pause
\only<n+1>{The gras \textshow{is} green}"
(n=currentslidenumber)
because i have to do this for about 200 times ?? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you want your overlays, it might avoid some duplication to use `alt`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\fib}[1]{\underline{\alt<+->{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
\begin{enumerate}
\item The gras \fib{is} green
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could shorten the code a bit with `\newcommand{\fib}[1]{\underline{\alt<+->{#1}{\phantom{#1}}}}`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz nice catch! That is indeed cleaner. I made the edit.

Comment: Nice solution!!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you! :)