# An alt fill-in-the-blank with question in the middle

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like to replace a fill in the blank with the answer. My question is related to this question: [How to make a fill-in-the-blank presentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/how-to-make-a-fill-in-the-blank-presentation/682139)
But I have a few additional specifications on my wishlist:

1. I want to replace the underline, so really what I'm after is replace-the-blank, not fill-in-the-blank.
2. I want to put a question mark horizontally centered in the middle of the blank (so it stands out more to students exactly where it is). I will color the question mark and the blank line.
3. I do not want any jumping when transitioning from the overlays.
4. I want the command to work inside math and outside.

I'll paste my naive attempt below. It has a couple of problems: I don't know how to put a question mark that is horizontally centered over the blank; and there is a jump on the last overlay, which I imagine is because the underline takes up some vertical space.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\doblankQ}[1]{\alert<.(1)>{\alt<+->{#1}{\textcolor{orange} {\uline{\phantom{#1}}}}}}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[<+->]

\begin{itemize}
\item One plus one is \doblankQ{two}.
\item And in math: $ 1 + 1 = \doblankQ{2}$.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the jumping problem you could `\smash` the underline to avoid it influencing the vertical space.

To add a `?` in the middle, I suggest to measure the width of the gap and then use `\makebox[<width of the gap>]{?}` instead of `\phantom{#1}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength{\gapwidth}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doblankQ}[1]{%
  \ifmmode
    \if@display
      \settowidth{\gapwidth}{$\displaystyle #1$}%
    \else
      \settowidth{\gapwidth}{$#1$}%
    \fi
  \else
    \settowidth{\gapwidth}{#1}%
  \fi
  \alert<.(1)>{%
    \alt<+->{%
      #1%
    }{%
      \vphantom{#1}\smash{\underline{\makebox[\gapwidth]{?}}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}[<+->]

\begin{itemize}
\item One plus one is \doblankQ{two}.
\item And in math: $ 1 + 1 = \doblankQ{2}$.
\item $\doblankQ{E(X_i)=40.}$
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, thank you! I came across one case that does not work well. If I change the second item to the following: `\item And in math: $\doblankQ{E(X_i)=40.}$`. I get the following error: `! Missing $ inserted.`. The issue triggering the problem seems to be the `_i`.

Comment: @scottkosty see my updated answer (only use this in inline math mode, the spacing might be wrong in displaystyle)

Comment: Works great, thanks! I'm sure I will accidentally use it in displaystyle at some point. Do you by chance have a recommendation for giving a helpful error in that case. e.g., "Scott: remember don't use doblankQ in displaymode".? Would `\mathchoice` be one way to accomplish this? No need to spend time on this or edit the question. Just curious if you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @scottkosty Actually it did not do what I wanted it to do, see again my updated answer

Comment: Works well! Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: @scottkosty It should now work with display style, too

Comment: Ah that is a nice bonus, thanks! I like your use of both `\vphantom` and `\smash`. It makes perfect sense but I just did not think of using them separately (i.e., not nested). The example seems to compile without the `soul` package. Can that be removed?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, it can be removed, that was just a leftover from some experimentation.

Comment: Great, thank you!